# How to search the first element of a list in python

Tags: python

So, essentially what I want to use is a keyed list but I couldn't see anything in Python for that.

Failing direct reading of a key I kind of wanted to do this:

```
for index in list[0]
```

which also doesn't work. I've got a list like:

```
 1,2
 3,7
 6,8
 9,11
```

I know the first element and I'm trying to find what second element maps to what first element.

So, if I have 6 I'm trying to find 8. Ideally without having to read each row until I get to the one I want.

The key is ordered ascending but is not sequential.

Comment: It sounds like you want a dictionary

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: are the elements unique or they are repeated?

Comment: for index in list[0] <- ???

Comment: Does it need to stay ordered?

Comment: the key field is unique

Comment: it does not need to stay ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
>>>d = {1: '2', 3: '7', 6: '8', 9: '11'}
```

Then to find something you can.

```
>>>d[3]
Out [ ]:
7
```

But this is not ordered.

Comment: That looks just the ticket!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get your data into dictionary form, if it is in string form like so:

```
1,2
3,4
...
```

Then

```
d = {k.split(',')[0]:k.split(',')[1] for k in data}
```

will give you the structure you want

d
   {'1':'2'...}

If you need the keys to be `int`s, then:

```
d = {int(k.split(',')[0]):k.split(',')[1] for k in data}

d
{1:'2', 3:'4'...}
```